# Table weigh shipping inspite of Show Method if Not Applicable

Tags: shipping-methods, multiple

I have 3 shipping methods, Flat Rate for U.S. only, Free Shipping for U.S. only and a Table Rate for International select countries. When in the cart if you enter an international location the Flat Rate and Free shipping options do not display as I have set "Show Method if Not Applicable" to No. However, if placing an order to be shipped to a U.S. location the International option (table rate) still displays even though I have set "Show Method if Not Applicable" to No and United States is not selected in the "Ship to Specific Countries" list.

Answer (score 0):

After poking around a bit I found the issue! I had set  *"Show Method if Not Applicable"* to No in the **Default Config** but not in the **Main Website** configuration.  So if you are having similar issues with any of multiple shipping methods showing or not showing, review your selections in the **Main Website** Configuration to make sure you have same shipping rules chosen as in the **Default Config**. (Use drop down menu of *Current Configuration Scope:* in top left hand corner to look at the Main Website view).